# How to handle the authentication token and and GraphQL client with Riverpod?

Tags: flutter, dart, graphql, riverpod

We are using **GraphQL** to connect our backend with our mobil application. We are using **Riverpod** to, among other things, handle global state, dependency injection, etc.

We are using a provider to handle the **GraphQL** cliente without any authentication header at first while the user is not authentication (this will handle unauthenticated request like login or registering), after the user is authenticated, a token provider who provides the token is updated and it must update the client provider who is user for every repository on the application:

```
final StateProvider<String> tokenProvider =
    StateProvider<String>((_) => '', name: "Token Provider");
```

```
final graphQLClientProvider = Provider<GraphQLClient>(
  (ref) {
    final String token = ref.watch(tokenProvider).state;

    final Link _link = HttpLink(
        'http://192.168.1.36:1337/graphql',
        defaultHeaders: {
          if (token != '') 'Authorization': 'Bearer $token',
        });

    return GraphQLClient(
      cache: GraphQLCache(),
      link: _link,
    );
  },
  name: "GraphQL Client Provider",
);
```

There is too problems here:

1. After updating the token, the client is changed, and from this, the function who updates the token does not finish in a proper way:

```sh
[ +141 ms] E/flutter ( 8361): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(199)] Unhandled Exception: Bad state: Tried to use AuthNotifier after `dispose` was called.
[        ] E/flutter ( 8361): 
[        ] E/flutter ( 8361): Consider checking `mounted`.
[        ] E/flutter ( 8361): 
[        ] E/flutter ( 8361): #0      StateNotifier._debugIsMounted.<anonymous closure> (package:state_notifier/state_notifier.dart:128:9)
[        ] E/flutter ( 8361): #1      StateNotifier._debugIsMounted (package:state_notifier/state_notifier.dart:135:6)
[        ] E/flutter ( 8361): #2      StateNotifier.state= (package:state_notifier/state_notifier.dart:155:12)
[        ] E/flutter ( 8361): #3      AuthNotifier.signIn (package:thesis_cancer/features/auth/application/auth.notifier.dart:84:7)
[        ] E/flutter ( 8361): <asynchronous suspension>
[        ] E/flutter ( 8361): #4      _LoginCardState._submit (package:flutter_login/src/widgets/auth_card.dart:503:15)
[        ] E/flutter ( 8361): <asynchronous suspension>
[        ] E/flutter ( 8361):
```

It means when the token is updated, the authentication notifier who receives the repository with depends on the provided client is updated/changes (following the chain):

```
final authRepositoryProvider = Provider<AuthRepository>(
  (ref) => GraphQLAuthRepository(client: ref.read(graphQLClientProvider)),
  name: 'Auth Repository Provider',
);

final authNotifierProvider = StateNotifierProvider<AuthNotifier, AuthState>(
  (ref) => AuthNotifier(
    authRepository: ref.watch(authRepositoryProvider),
    dataStore: ref.watch(dataStoreRepositoryProvider),
    profileRepository: ref.watch(profileRepositoryProvider),
    tokenController: ref.watch(tokenProvider.notifier),
    userController: ref.watch(userEntityProvider.notifier),
  ),
  name: "Authentication Notifier Provider",
);
```

The notification function who breaks at the conditional(**if**):

```
Future<String?> signIn({
    required String username,
    required String password,
  }) async {
    try {
      final Map<String, dynamic> rawUser = await authRepository.signIn(
          identifier: username, password: password) as Map<String, dynamic>;
      final User sessionUser = User.fromJson(rawUser);
      if (sessionUser.confirmed != false) {
        tokenController.state = sessionUser.token!; <-- Bug begins here
      }
      await dataStore.writeUserProfile(sessionUser);
      userController.state = sessionUser;
      state = const AuthState.loggedIn();
    } on LogInFailureByBadRequest {
      return "E-posta veya şifre geçersiz.";
    } on LogInFailure catch (error) {
      return error.toString();
    }
  }
```

2. While the client appears to be changed when the token is updated, the client itself does not reflect the change (it does not include the authentication header with the token) and thus breaks the GraphQL client:
   [image]

Following the comments on [the issue we opened](https://github.com/rrousselGit/river_pod/issues/496), we added the `ProviderReference` to our notifier (following [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65666935/3826549)) but it does not work:

```
 AuthNotifier(
    this._ref, {
    required this.authRepository,
    required this.profileRepository,
    required this.dataStore,
    required this.tokenController,
    required this.userController,
  }) : super(const AuthState.loading());
  final ProviderReference _ref;
  final ProfileRepository profileRepository;
  final AuthRepository authRepository;
  final DataStoreRepository dataStore;
  final StateController<User?> userController;
  final StateController<String> tokenController;
```

At this point, we don't understand what's the problem here.

*UPDATE*

We removed this changes both in the *StateNotifier* and its provider.

Getting the client at repository by read does not avoid the error:
[image]

What's the proper way to handle the authorization token and the **GraphQL** client with **Riverpod**?

Thank you.

Comment: What version of Riverpod are you using?

Comment: I'm still using `hooks_riverpod: ^0.14.0+4`.

Comment: Add the fragment where you use the authNotifier

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is the `authRepositoryProvider`:

```dart
final authRepositoryProvider = Provider<AuthRepository>(
  (ref) => GraphQLAuthRepository(client: ref.read(graphQLClientProvider)),
  name: 'Auth Repository Provider',
);
```

In this fragment, the `authRepositoryProvider` is using a `GraphQLClient` without token. When the token is updated, the `graphQLClientProvider` state is well updated, but the `authRepositoryProvider` isn't because you are using `ref.read` avoiding the rebuild of the `authRepositoryProvider` state. This implies that the `authRepositoryProvider` knows a disposed (and unmounted) state of `graphQLClientProvider` and that's why the error message.

There are 2 solutions:

1. Using `ref.watch`:

```dart
final authRepositoryProvider = Provider<AuthRepository>(
  (ref) => GraphQLAuthRepository(client: ref.watch(graphQLClientProvider)),
  name: 'Auth Repository Provider',
);
```

2. Passing the `ref.read` as parameter:

```dart
final authRepositoryProvider = Provider<AuthRepository>(
  (ref) => GraphQLAuthRepository(client: ref.read),
  name: 'Auth Repository Provider',
);

class AuthRepository {
  AuthRepository(this.read)

  final Reader read;

  GraphQLClient get client => read(graphQLClientProvider);
}
```

Be care about using `read` and `watch`, the first one does not react to the changes but could be used anywhere, while the second one reacts to a provider's state update but only can be used in another provider constructor or in a widget that provides access to a `watch` or `ref.watch` depending on the version of Riverpod.

In addition, there is another problem in your code:

```dart
  final User sessionUser = User.fromJson(rawUser);
  if (sessionUser.confirmed != false) {
    // In this moment, the token is updated,
    // then the QrahpQLClient is updated,
    // then the AuthNotifier is recreated,
    // i.e the current is disposed
    // and now becomes the previous
    tokenController.state = sessionUser.token!; <-- Bug begins here
  }
  await dataStore.writeUserProfile(sessionUser);
  userController.state = sessionUser;

  // In this moment you are updating the state of a disposed notifier
  state = const AuthState.loggedIn();
```

To provide a solution it is necessary to define which elements will make rebuild the `AuthNotifer.state` instead of recreating the notifier.

You must consider access to another notifiers bases on the `ref.read` and manually create the subscriptions in the StateController constructor.

In the future, when riverpod 1.0 will be released, this issue will be easy with `ref.listen` but now you need to rewrite your code. You can take inspiration in the `bloc-to-bloc` communication gide: https://bloclibrary.dev/#/architecture?id=bloc-to-bloc-communication

Comment: Ok, i tried the first one and the problem stil persist, so, i guess the solution is the second one. Thank you.

Comment: No success with the second one.

Answer (score 1):

i think the error is in your AuthNotifier:

```
  if (sessionUser.confirmed != false) {
    tokenController.state = sessionUser.token!; <-- you are updating a dependencie of your actual AuthNotifier object
  }
  await dataStore.writeUserProfile(sessionUser); <-- during the await a new object is created and the actual instance is disposed so this line will throw
```

Comment: Yeah, that's the problem, so, how can we solve it?

Comment: replace tokenController: ref.watch(tokenProvider.notifier), by tokenController: ref.read(tokenProvider.notifier)
in your authNotifierProvider